How do I read a register of a pyrometer over NModbus in C#?
I am new to MODBus, but have worked with Profibus/PLC before. I am trying to use C# NModbus package to communicate with two pyrometers using RS485. The system is set up as so:
|Computer| -> |RS485 to USB| -> |Slave 1| -> |Slave 2|
The pyrometers I am using have this list of RTU commands. I can get readings from each one individually using the pyrometers' proprietary software, so I know my wiring is correct. I have my code which finds connected COM ports, and then allows the user to select a COM # to connect to.
 private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string comNumber = tb_COM.Text;

            myCOM.ConfigureAndOpen(comNumber, 115200);

            SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM10", Constants.BaudRate, Constants.Parity, Constants.DataBits, Constants.StopBits);

            // Create the Modbus factory
            var factory = new ModbusFactory();
            var adapter = new SerialPortAdapter(myCOM.port);
            IModbusSerialMaster master = factory.CreateRtuMaster(adapter);

            // Read data from the first pyrometer(slave ID 1)
            byte slaveId1 = 1;
            ushort startAddress1 = 10000; // Input register address for the first pyrometer
            ushort numRegisters1 = 1; // Number of registers to read
            byte command1 = 0x04;
            ushort[] registers1 = master.ReadInputRegisters(slaveId1, startAddress1, numRegisters1);
            Console.WriteLine($"Pyrometer 1 Reading: {registers1[0]}");
            tb_Display.AppendText($"Pyrometer 1 Reading: {registers1[0]}");

            // Read data from the second pyrometer (slave ID 2)
            byte slaveId2 = 2;
            ushort startAddress2 = 10000; // Input register address for the second pyrometer
            ushort numRegisters2 = 1; // Number of registers to read
            byte command2 = 0x04;
            ushort[] registers2 = master.ReadInputRegisters(slaveId2, startAddress2, numRegisters2);
            Console.WriteLine($"Pyrometer 2 Reading: {registers2[0]}");
            tb_Display.AppendText($"Pyrometer 2 Reading: {registers2[0]}");

            timer1.Enabled = true;
            timer1.Start();
        }

When I press the "Connect" button, my program stops responding. When I debugged this, it was stopping on the first "ReadInputRegisters" line, and the thread would die.
I'm stuck now, not sure of how to proceed as I'm not sure what is going wrong. My guesses have been to:

Use a RTU slave network instead of a Master (also could not get this to work)
Maybe my computer cannot be the master and I need to have an arduino or PLC inbetween the sensors?
Try to follow as deep as I can into NModbus and see where the fail happens (Happens in ModbusTransport.UnicastMessage, at "response=ReadResponse, but I have no idea why).

How can I get the temperature readings off of the pyrometers?

Start by inspecting the exception you get, and you likely want some error handling as well. I have only used Modbus TCP, but your code looks reasonable to me. I would suggest using a third party tool, like RMMS to verify that all the hardware works. I think it handles RTU as well as TCP.

You can use the command line utility mbpoll to verify that your configuration is correct, e.g., mbpoll -m rtu -a 1 -b 9600 -d 8 -s 2 -P even -r 1020 -c 4 -t 3 -1 COM10 to try to read the temperature input registers. Otherwise [edit] your question to include a [mre] so it's possible to help you.
